# Remove EmptyDataTemplate border

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView in ASP.NET with custom CSS styling, including a border.  The EmptyItemTemplate has a message: "No results found" but has a border which I want to remove.  I know about this code:

```
<EmptyDataRowStyle BorderWidth="0" />
```

However, this applies to the row, not the table itself--so the table border remains.  I've also tried applying a custom CSS class to the EmptyDataRowStyle, but this applies to the row, not the table itself.

So how do I remove the border on the EmptyDataTemplate?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [GridView Empty DataTemplate Get Rid of that Annoying Border](http://www.jonathanjungman.com/blog/post/GridView-EmptyDataTemplate-Get-Rid-of-That-Annoying-Border!.aspx)

Comment: Thanks--I already tried that.  The author sets the gridview default border to 0, but I want to keep the border if there's actual data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery.  I added this to the GridView:

```
<EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyData" />
```

And then added this jQuery at the bottom of the page:

```
$(".EmptyData").parents("table").css("border-width", "0px").prop("border", "0");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for.  Thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 3):

Use only CSS

```
<EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyData" />

.EmptyData td {
    border-width: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by adding `GridLines="None"`:

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="dv" CssClass="noborder" GridLines="None">
```

CSS:

```
.noborder { border: none }
```