# Why extra cells generate automatically?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, cell, generated

My problem is that, in my GridView, empty cells are generated automatically. I'd like for them to not appear. I have both ShowHeaderWhenEmpty and AutoGenerateColumns at false and the same amount for *TempateField*s, *th*s and *td*s. Here's how it appears:

When empty, there's one empty cell above the first column.

After a PostBack, but still empty, there's empty cell that takes the entire row above.

But, when there's data, it is perfect.

I can't post images because I have not enough reputation, but I hope you still visualize and understand.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewCommentaires" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false"
        ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderColor="Black">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldIdCommentaire" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("[idCommentaire]") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelCommentaireDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("dtHrEntree")).ToString("d") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" runat="server" ID="TextBoxCommentaireDate" Enabled="false"
                        BorderStyle="None" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Entré par" ItemStyle-Width="175">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelCommentaireModifiePar" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[modifieParComplet]") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" runat="server" ID="TextBoxCommentaireModifiePar" Enabled="false"
                        BorderStyle="None" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commentaire" ItemStyle-Width="725">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelCommentaire" Width="700px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[commentaire]") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" ID="TextBoxCommentaire" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSupprimerCommentaire" CssClass="ImageSupprimer" OnClick="LinkButtonSupprimerCommentaire_Click"
                        Text="" ToolTip="Supprimer" runat="server" ForeColor="Transparent" Width="16px"
                        Height="16px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Supprimer le commentaire ?')" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAjouterCommentaire" CssClass="ImageSauvegarder" OnClick="LinkButtonAjouterCommentaire_Click"
                        Text="" ToolTip="Ajouter" runat="server" ForeColor="Transparent" Width="16px"
                        Height="16px" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    Date
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Entré par
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Commentaire
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px">
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" runat="server" ID="TextBoxCommentaireDate" Enabled="false"
                        BorderStyle="None" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 175px">
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" runat="server" ID="TextBoxCommentaireModifiePar" Enabled="false"
                        BorderStyle="None" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 725px">
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100%" ID="TextBoxCommentaire" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" />
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAjouterCommentaire" CssClass="ImageSauvegarder" OnClick="LinkButtonAjouterCommentaire_Click"
                        ToolTip="Ajouter" runat="server" ForeColor="Transparent" Width="16px"
                        Height="16px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

That is very weird. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the reason for this behavior is inconsistent markup that you receive for no data. `EmptyDataTemplate` is used to defined the content of the row to show for empty data set:

> The empty data row is displayed in a GridView control when the data source that is bound to the control does not contain any records. You can define your own custom user interface (UI) for the empty data row by using the EmptyDataTemplate property.

So what I think is happening is that your markup is inserted inside the `tr` tag created by the GridView, thus giving you a markup like this:

```
<table>                <-- comes from GridView
    <tr>               <-- comes from GridView
        <tr>           <-- comes from your template
            <th>...
        </tr>
        <tr>           <-- comes from your template
            <td>...
        </tr>
```

That could easily lead to UI fluctuations.

Simple fix, although I am not 100% sure it will work, is to wrap your template in proper `<table>` tag:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>...
    </table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

If you have issues with the style of `EmptyDataTemplate`, use `EmptyDataRowStyle` to control its appearance:

> To control the style of the empty data row, use the EmptyDataRowStyle property.

Another approach would be to rethink the way you treat no data case, perhaps hide GridView completely and show some panel with textboxes inside.

Comment: That's super! The only thing is that the EmptyDataTemplate makes another layer of border and I'm not able to remove it. Also tried with the EmptyDataRowStyle and It doesn't remove it. An idea?

Comment: @Yannick, it was on the same MSDN page. See update to the post

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an exemple?

Comment: @Yannick, sure, something like this should do it: `<EmptyDataRowStyle BorderStyle="None"/>`

Comment: It doesn't work, I wonder why... I even tried with CssClass and it didn't work also. I googled and seems like I'm not the only one having issues with EmptyDataRowStyle and EmptyDataTemplate. They say the solution was css, but it didn't work for me... :s

Comment: @Yannick, indeed people have issues with that. Have a look at [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242910/remove-emptydatatemplate-border).

Comment: I tried this solution with the jquery too and it didn't work also.
So finally, I ended up on removing the EmptyDataRowStyle, and I just added the property Frame="Void" to the table with the border collapsed and it somehow looked pretty awesome!!
So the properties of my table in the EmptyDataTemplate is
    <table border="1px" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-color: Black" frame="void">
Thanks for all Andrei!